# how to close or return a loaded div to it's original state

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an **index.php** with a **#container** div that has content, and an **#open** button.
on the page are also 2 tabs.

```
...
<div id="Tabs">
    <div id="content1Tab"></div>
    <div id="content2Tab"></div>
</div>
<div id="container">
   <div id="content1">
       ..someContent...
       <button id="open1">Open</button>
   </div>
   <div id="content2">
       ..someContent...
       <button id="open2">Open</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

clicking on **content1Tab** brings **content1** to the forefront of **container**, using `z-index`.

clicking on **content2Tab** brings **content2** to the front.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#content1Tab, #content2Tab).click(function(event) {
            var myString = $(this).attr('id');
            var parts = myString.split("Tab");
            var thePart = parts[0];

            $("#content1, #content2).css('z-index', 7);
            $("#"+thePart).css('z-index',9);
       });
...
```

clicking on **open1** successfully loads **container** with the contents of **containerOther** div from **page.php.**

```
$('#open1').click(function(){
        $("#container").load("../page.php #containerOther> *");
    });
```

I want a click on the tab to reload the original contents of the **container**. How can I do this?

I tried:

```
$("#content1Tab, #content2Tab).click(function(event) {            
        $("#container").load("../index.php #container > *");
       ....
    });
```

but then the **container** stays on **content1** no matter what tab I click on, and the **open1** doesn't do anything. debugging showed that clicking doesn't enter the js code. I tried:

```
 $("#container").load("../index.php #"+thePart);
```

the **content** changes according to the tab click, but the button still doesn't work.
both **index** and **page** have a link to the js file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I follow it correctly, it is chancing content of the #container where first the button was bound to jQuery functionality.
This way the binds will get lost and as result nothing happens when you click on those buttons again.

Solution is to bind again after the content has been refreshed, with a callback function I think:

```
$('#container').load("../index.php #"+thePart, function() {
    $('#open1').click(function(){
        $("#container").load("../page.php #containerOther> *");
    });
});
```

I think a separate function for binding after the content refresh is better, because if you use the code here above, the binding problem will happens after the first successful content refreshment :).

Comment: It work! thanks. What did you mean "seperate function for binding after refresh"?

Comment: Cool! O maybe I’ve got that separate function wrong now I think of it :)! So no need for that if it keeps on working all good this way.

Comment: Is there a better way to just reload the div`s original content from the index page?

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to accomplish, I don't get the full picture. You mean this  $("#container").load("../index.php #"+thePart);   ?  I would place those buttons outside of the #content1 and #content2 div's to prevent the binding problem. And you can also save the loaded content in a variable, like    var origin =  $('#content1').html();    instead of the load (AJAX).